# PEPhotoCropEditor cropview.croprect being ignored

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, cgrect

Using [PEPhotoCropEditor](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/PEPhotoCropEditor) I'm trying to set cropview.croprect but the rect seem to ignore it and still calculate the rect based on the image size. Meanwhile .cropRect works well if I use a controller to access it.

What I'm trying to do is create a fix cropview regardless of what image is selected.

Here's my code:

```
cropView = [[PECropView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
cropView.image = coverPhotoView.image;
cropView.cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 173);
[self.view addSubview:cropView];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your initialisation code into ViewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    cropView = [[PECropView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    cropView.image = coverPhotoView.image;
    [self.view addSubview:cropView];
}
```

And then set your CropRect in ViewDidAppear:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    cropView.cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 173);
}
```